# How to program Power Spectrum of .wav file

Tags: python, audio, scipy

So I am trying to calculate the power spectrum of noise I recorded from the sun from a .wav file it recorded to. So far my code is (NEW CODE FROM OLD POST):

```
import pyaudio
import sys
import struct
import numpy
from pylab import *
import wave
import pyfits

sundata = ('sun_noise_ouput.wav')
chunk = 1024
FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16-bit integers
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 25000
RECORD_SECONDS = 120

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()

# Convert to pair of bytes to numerical datatype 
N = len(sundata)/2
data = numpy.zeros(N,dtype=float)
for i in range(N) :
data[i] = struct.unpack('h',sundata[2*i:2*(i+1)])[0]

column = pyfits.Column(name='integer data', array=data, format="J")

fitsoutput = pyfits.new_table([column]) 


fitsoutput.writeto('sun_noise_output.fits', clobber=True)

wf = wave.open('sun_noise_output.wav', 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(CHANNELS)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
wf.setframerate(RATE)
wf.writeframes(sundata)
wf.close()


dataft = numpy.fft.fft(data)

powerspectrum = abs(dataft)**2

figure()
plot(range(N),data)


figure()
plot(range(N),powerspectrum)

show()
```

May also help to note that when I try playing the file it returns no audio and says it has length 0:00 seconds

Also when I downlaod a sample from NASA's homepage there is no playback audio and these are the graphs produced:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which line caused the error?  Please include the complete traceback in the question.

Comment: @vikramls's answer was deleted, but the idea was sound. Your file might be corrupted.  Can you read "sun_noise_output.wav" with some other software without an error? For example, in python you could try `import wave; w = wave.open('sun_noise_output.wav'); print w.getsampwidth()`; see the `wave` library, https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html, for more information.